# How to plot parts of rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

My pandas dataframe looks like this

```
        A_month1  A_month2  B_month1 B_month2
Train1         1         9         6        3
Train2         7         0         3        9
Train3         4         2         0        2
...
```

I want to make a line plot that shows how A changes from month1 to month2 that includes all 3 lines (that is, rows Train1, Train2 and Train3). I want my x-axis to be from `A_month1`  to `A_month2`, and my y-axis to range from 0 to 10. Something like this :

[image]

All I found when searching online was how to plot lines with whole columns as the y-axis.

How do I write that?

I have looked through google for a while and not found anything that looks like this. I looked at the documentation for matplotlib and pandas.DataFrame.plot, but I didnt find anything there that looks like my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
use_cols = ["A_month1", "A_month2"]

#for more colors : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html
colors = ["orange", "dodgerblue", "greenyellow"] #I replaced the yellow with dodgerblue

ax = (
    df[use_cols].T.plot(
        legend=True, color=colors, linewidth=4, ylim=(0, 10), xticks=[0, 1])
)

for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_linewidth(3)

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am currently "too new" (after over 10 years of using this site) to upvote you. But this worked perfectly! The main thing i got wrong originally was not using double square brackets, as you're essentially doing, in specifying which columns to plot.

In the next project I would like to plot the same, but where A_month1 and A_month2 are in different dataframes. Is that even possible to plot as is? Or do I have to make a new dataFrame with both in it?

Comment: You're welcome ;) And regarding your question, yes it is possible to make such plot even if the columns are hold with different. However, without seeing how looks like those dfs, I can't propose a way to do it. Feel free to [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a minimal reproducible example.